# XF iOS project on Mac OS with Visual Studio community - XAML Hot Reload is disabled because your iOS Linker Settings for … are unsupported message

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can anyone help me.  I have been seeing this message for the a very long time and cannot resolve it:

XAML Hot Reload is disabled because your iOS Linker Settings for … are unsupported.   Set your Linker Behavior to “Don’t Link” and rebuild your project to use Hot Reload

I follow the instructions but it never seems to stop the message:

[image]

Would also appreciate advice from others on the build settings.  These are the default for new iOS projects but are they correct ones and are they the ones you use?

Comment: Hi, what is the version of your vs for mac? You could update it to the latest version and 
also need to keep the version of Xcode be the latest.

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.7.9 (build 9)
Installation UUID: 5b49994c-5136-4f08-a7dd-b3684b28fc14
 GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
 Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

Comment: My Xcode is the latest.  I tried various versions of VS including pre-release and always the same message appears with instructions to do what has already been done.

Comment: Okey, after setting the linker, you could **Re-Enable XAML Hot Reload for Xamarin.Forms** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#enable-xaml-hot-reload-for-xamarinforms